# Como resolver erro no while?

Tags: python, django

Estou criando uma lógica de boletos no Django, onde eu queria que ao criar um boleto fosse criada determinadas datas de vencimentos. Então fiz os seguintes códigos:

`models:`

```
class Boleto(models.Model):
beneficiario = models.CharField(max_length=20)
registro = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
valor_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
parcela = models.IntegerField(default=0)
filtro = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='CONTA')
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS)
departamento = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=DEPARTAMENTO)

class Vencimento(models.Model):
boletos = models.ForeignKey("Boleto", related_name="datas", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
vencimentos = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
valor_parcela = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

`html`

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'financeiro:add_boleto' %}"  autocomplete="off">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="beneficiario" maxlength="100" placeholder="NOME" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="valor" maxlength="50" placeholder="VALOR" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="valor_total" maxlength="50" placeholder="VALOR TOTAL" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="parcela" maxlength="50" placeholder="NÚMERO DE PARCELAS" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <select class="form-control" aria-label="TIPO DE ENTRADA"  name="status" required>
                        <option selected>STATUS</option>
                        <option value="EM DIA">EM DIA</option>
                        <option value="PAGO">PAGO</option>
                        <option value="ATRASADO">ATRASADO</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <select class="form-control" aria-label="TIPO DE ENTRADA"  name="departamento" required>
                        <option selected>Departamento</option>
                        <option value="FINANCEIRO">FINANACEIRO</option>
                        <option value="OFICINA">OFICINA</option>
                        <option value="MARKETING">MARKETING</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" >CANCELAR</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    SALVAR
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

É no código abaixo que esta o problema

```
def add_boleto(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    if request.POST.get('beneficiario') \
            and request.POST.get('parcela') \
            and request.POST.get('status') \
            and request.POST.get('valor_total') \
            or request.POST.get('departamento'):
        boleto = Boleto()
        boleto.beneficiario = request.POST.get('beneficiario')
        boleto.valor = request.POST.get('valor')
        boleto.valor_total = request.POST.get('valor_total')
        boleto.parcela = request.POST.get('parcela')
        boleto.status = request.POST.get('status')
        boleto.departamento = request.POST.get('departamento')
        valor_total = boleto.valor_total
        parcela = boleto.parcela

        valor_parcela = int(valor_total) / int(parcela)
        data_atual = boleto.registro
        boleto.save()

        lista_vencimento = Vencimento.objects.filter(boletos=boleto)
        n_parcelas = int(parcela)

        while len(lista_vencimento) < n_parcelas:

            vencimento = Vencimento()
            td = timedelta(30)

            vencimento_data = data_atual + td
            vencimento.vencimentos = vencimento_data
            vencimento.valor_parcela = valor_parcela
            vencimento.boletos = boleto
            vencimento.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/financeiro")
```

O que eu tentei é ao criar um boleto, fosse criado um numero de Vencimentos igual o número de parcelas, utilizei então o while.
Os vencimentos são criados, porém infinitamente, me levando a crer que há um problema nas variáveis passadas no While, entretanto não sei como resolver, e gostaria de ajuda em relação a isso. Desde já agradeço!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Veja que para que um `while` pare de executar é preciso que a condição utilizada com ele torne-se `false`.

No seu trecho de código podemos ver que essa condição jamais se tornará `false`, visto que a consulta (*query*) realizada antes do `while` manterá o mesmo valor, sem alterar-se, durante todos os ciclos do `while`.

Creio que você gostaria que o número de objetos retornados por essa *query* fosse diminuindo e, de fato, no seu banco de dados eles devem estar diminuindo. O problema é que a consulta (*query*) feita a esse banco de dados não está sendo refeita, logo a informação armazenada na variável `lista_vencimento` está sempre desatualizada.

Comment: Realmente, eu adicionei a consulta query depois de salvar o vencimento, e funcionou como eu esperava, obrigado pelo suporte!